# React Admin - can a product be assigned to multiple categories?

Tags: react-admin

Can products in the react-admin framework be assigned to multiple categories?

For example in the demo, a new poster of a bearded man with a pet cat would ideally be categorised as both 'beard' and 'animal'. Currently you can only select one category.

You are able to specify multiple segments for a customer in the demo (using alt-select in the customer's segment drop-down list) so I wondered why this feature was not enabled for product categories...

In addition, can filtering then be configured to support multiple category filtering, rather than only allowing one single category term to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we could have implemented it this way for product categories too. We didn't as we wanted to show multiple types of references in the demo.

As for your question about filtering, yes, it's possible if you use the same input as for segments selection which allow multiple ones.

React-admin is a framework for building administration applications with React. It's not an e-commerce framework nor a UI kit. You can do whatever you want :)